# App like Navbar when resize website to mobile view

Tags: web-applications, responsive-design, navbar

I am creating a static website with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The website is fully responsive when resizing and testing in Desktop/Tablet/Mobile view.

What i am struggling to figure out is how do i resize the navbar (menu) in a way that when i am using the desktop/tablet view it looks like a normal website navbar then when i try the mobile view there is a navbar at the bottom like how an app would have. Something like when you go on a website like takealot.com website.

[This is the normal top navbar for desktop/tablet view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoOJD.png)

[This is the bottom navbar that i am intending on doing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH6JM.png)

## Please advise on a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you can achieve this, but you'll have to do a bit of planning before getting started to see which route you want / need to take.

Ask yourself:

- Do the two different navigation solutions include the same content?
- Can the two different navigation solutions include the same code hierarchy?

If the answer is "no" to either of those, I'd go with creating two different html components and dynamically hiding / showing then depending on the viewport size with media queries.

If the answer is "yes" to both you'll likely have to carefully plan out the syntax of your markup so that the nav items can be displayed similarly (though you will 100% need to utilize media queries to change the *look* of the two depending on the viewport sizing).

If you're having trouble with displaying them in different areas (larger viewports near the top, smaller viewports at the bottom) try utilizing `position: absolute;` and even flexbox to swap the display order of your elements.